# App crashing after returning from background on iOS6

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios6

I have an app that has been running fine on iOS 5, but after some testing on iOS 6, it runs fine except for when returning to the app after it has been running. Once it returns from the background it is unresponsive and then crashes about 10 seconds later.

WillEnterForeground() is executed fine and there is only some simple code in there.

Checking the console on the phone, I see the following:

```
Sep 20 16:41:07 Seans-iPhone-4 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[985] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Sep 20 16:41:07 Seans-iPhone-4 kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[985] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/F73BBA70-90D1-4CB6-B7F3-FF10289396A9 (sandbox)
Sep 20 16:41:29 Seans-iPhone-4 backboardd[52] <Warning>: TrekkTrakker failed to resume in time
Sep 20 16:41:29 Seans-iPhone-4 backboardd[52] <Warning>: Forcing crash report of TrekTrakkerSimp[985]...
Sep 20 16:41:30 Seans-iPhone-4 backboardd[52] <Warning>: Finished crash reporting.
Sep 20 16:41:30 Seans-iPhone-4 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:TrekkTrakker[0x28c2][985]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:TrekkTrakker[0x28c2]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 20 16:41:30 Seans-iPhone-4 backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:TrekkTrakker[0x28c2]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 20 16:41:30 Seans-iPhone-4 ReportCrash[987] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Sep 20 16:41:31 Seans-iPhone-4 ReportCrash[987] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TrekTrakkerSimple_2012-09-20-164129_Seans-iPhone-4.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Anyone experiencing similar issues, or have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: what was under processing (in code) when the app went to background??

Answer (score 0):

If your not using ARC it is in all likelihood an issue with something being released that your sending a message to. Just about every version of iOS that has come out has exposed some bug that was always there but which for whatever reason was not surfaced until the new Version.

Run in the debugger and look at all the code in the levels near where it crashed for something stupid like an object that is not retained or which you though was but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing or rather being forced to exit by WatchDog because the app is not responsive in the 10 second window. This means that your app is taking too long to launch, this could be due to a call that is getting stuck on iOS 6 or more likely the iOS 6 device is running slightly slower for one reason or another. Use the Time Profiler instrument to look at where your startup time is going and ensure that applicationDidFinishLaunching: is returning as quickly as possible, most cases of WatchDog crashes are due to hangups in that method.